# Can't access app / IIS external from VM but can access from within VM

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

We have an app / IIS server that runs on a Windows Server 2016 machine that we are able to access the app's functionality from within the VM(http://localhost) but we are not able to access the app from an external machine i.e. http://hostnameofserver.

Windows firewall is turned off, can ping server but cannot telnet to port 80.
No recent updates were installed or changes to network configuration.

Are there any other obvious places / techniques I can check / perform to troubleshoot this further?

Thank you!

Comment: From another machine, does the hostnameofserver resolve to the current/correct IP of the VM guest?

Comment: Yes, it resolves to the correct ip.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run a report to learn the site bindings first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the server where the app was on was rolled back to a previous snapshot where the app worked. Very strange that this randomly happened, is it common to have IIS lose bindings to ports?

Answer (score 0):

This may be entirely wrong for your situation, but it worked on Server 2012 back in the day. Turn firewall back on. Create 2 rules: 1 ingress (in) and one egress (out) and set them as ANY/ANY. Then turn the firewall back off and see if that works.